# MySQL: How can I get the timestamp of the last insertion to the database

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, database-schema, information-schema

How can I check when was the last time (timestamp) that I wrote in the database, irrespectively of the database table that I inserted into?

Comment: Do you need to distinguish INSERT from UPDATE and DELETE?  Also, are you seeking the last update by your specific user ID, or the last update of any sort to the database? It actually doesn't make much difference; the information you seek is unlikely to be available whether you want 'any update' or 'insert specifically'.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I am interested only in INSERT (any sort of the latter to the database).

Comment: Then my OTHER answer will be perfect, please unaccept my first and accept my second.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Just use this SQL: `SHOW TABLE STATUS;` and check **Update_time** column.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will not work properly with InnoDB, see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add a field for modified date in the table and use LAST_INSERT_ID() to determine the last row (if you're doing it right away). Otherwise just retrieve the most recent date from the modified field for the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what **logging is all about**.

On the CLI

1. execute `SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';`
2. execute `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`

Now, a table `general_log` inside `mysql` database will log all such actions on database.
Use phpMyadmin or similar to view these. You can query from their results very effectively.