# How to get the last inserted date and time in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the date and time when the last insertion had happened.

I tried this :

```
 SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
```

This gave me last updated time but not the one I needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "not the one I needed." What exactly did you need then, if not that?

Comment: if you have created datetime field in your table why cant you jusr use `SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @ADyson: 'not the one I needed ' means I want last insert time not the last updated time

Comment: See various answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657206/mysql-how-can-i-get-the-timestamp-of-the-last-insertion-to-the-database - basically it seems that unless you turn on more verbose logging, you can't really distinguish between update/insert/delete operations on the table.